# Airflow db clean command

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm using the airflow db clean command on AF version 2.3.3 (the most up-to date version in GCP Composer) and the some of the metadata tables are not being cleared by that command airflow db clean: e.g. dag_runs. I've checked the DB manually and the entries are there. I have even executed the following command:

```sql
SELECT base.*
FROM dag_run AS base LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT dag_id, max(dag_run.start_date) AS max_date_per_group
FROM dag_run
WHERE external_trigger = false GROUP BY dag_id) AS latest ON base.dag_id = latest.dag_id AND base.start_date = max_date_per_group
WHERE base.start_date < '2023-01-01' AND max_date_per_group IS NULL;
```

which should be the one used during the clean-up, and I obtained a non-empty result.

Is this a know issue please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Airflow officially recommends to stop using that and to move into `airflow cli`. You can find it [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#clean)